# How can I insert 2 or 3 rows to the same table using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I try to insert in my table Days 2 or 3 entities like "day Saturday Group A" 
and "day Monday  Same Group A" and "Friday Same group A"

```
using (db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    List<Group_Days_TB> groupadd = new List<Group_Days_TB>();
    groupadd.Add(new Group_Days_TB()
    {
        ID_Groups = int.Parse(TxtID.Text.ToString()),
        ID_Days = int.Parse(listBoxControl1.SelectedValue.ToString()),
        GSelectedTime = TimeSpan.Parse(textEdit1.Time.ToString("HH:mm")),
        GStartdate = DateTime.Parse(timeEdit1.Text.ToString()),
        GEnddate = DateTime.Parse(timeEdit2.Text.ToString())
    });
    db.Group_Days_TBs.InsertAllOnSubmit(groupadd);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The insert's last day I choose from listbox. 
it's just insert 1 day not all days i selected

Comment: AFAIU, you use LINQ-to-SQL and something doesn't work when you call `SubmitChanges`. Can you tell what exactly doesn't work? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, I'd at least expect some code that loops through the selected values of, I assume, `listBoxControl1` (do something about these default names).

Comment: There is only one Group_Days_TB object in your groupadd list.You should create object and add it your list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the selected values in your ListBox

```
        using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            List<Group_Days_TB> groupadd = new List<Group_Days_TB>();
            foreach (int i in listBoxControl1.SelectedIndices)
            {
                groupadd.Add(new Group_Days_TB(
                    int.Parse(TxtID.Text.ToString()),
                    int.Parse(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(listBoxControl1.Items[i])[listBoxControl1.ValueMember].ToString()),
                    TimeSpan.Parse(textEdit1.Text.ToString()),
                    DateTime.Parse(timeEdit1.Text.ToString()),
                    DateTime.Parse(timeEdit2.Text.ToString())
                    ));
            }
            db.Group_Days_TBs.InsertAllOnSubmit(groupadd);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

I created a parameterized constructor in Group_Days_TB for adding to the list, but that's just my preference.

I've never used the TypeDescriptor.GetProperties before but I believe that line will pull the Value Member for the current selected index